# browsers using different java versions on same PC

Tags: java, browser

Good day All,

I have java 6 update 27 (32-bit) and java 7 update 51 (64-bit) installed on my Windows 7 64-bit, i want to make IE use the java 6 whilst the google Chrome use the java 7.

Thank you

Comment: It's better to be asked on Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain,  but I think you can type chrome://plugins in the browser and it will allow you to adjust your settings on chrome.  As for ie,  you might have to go into the properties and adjust them.

Comment: I already tried to edit the plugin settings to no avail, it does not allow me edit even though i'm logged in as a local Admin. I am looking for a way, if possible, to edit the java path for just Google Chrome in the registry, any ideas??

Comment: Have you tried removing chrome and redownloading it.  Then just installing the java plugin you want?